# How does the Cuphead difficulty level change when one player dies in two player co-op?

Tags: cuphead

When playing two player co-op mode in Cuphead there seems to be a significant drop in difficultly when one member of the team dies.

It's my hunch that after a death the difficultly drops to one player mode level difficulty, but I can't be sure.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

When you are playing 2 player mode in Cuphead, the bosses health is doubled, and your attacks are halved. When someone dies, or Player 2 gets kicked, the bosses health is unaffected, but your damage is back to normal again.

Answer (score 1):

It is more difficult because a lot of mechanisms are based on your position. When you are 2, it is more difficult to know when the bullet will target your character, and if you don't move as a same person you have a risk to be hit by old position of the second character.

The hardest part is the Run'n'gun, as every event is triggered by your move, so if the second player is behind you he'll get the delayed event, so less natural from his position. I'm not sure I'm making sense haha, you need to test by yourself!

I think the revive is a plus though